# How to Separate server name and instance name from @@servername in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I separate Server name and Named instance from @@servername. I know I could just use serverproperty to collect just the Machine name or instance name but I am working with two tables where I have to join on the table name. Table1 has the just the Server name as an "TESTDB01" and Table2 has Server Name and the Instance name as an TESTDB01\InstanceName.

When I Join these tables together, anything with the Named Instances will be missed as it has "\InstanceName" , only the default Instance will get picked up.

[image: See Attached Pic]

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
LEFT(@@SERVERNAME,CHARINDEX('\',@@SERVERNAME)-1)
```

But you would be better off separating them in your table in order to make your queries sargable.  Join conditions using these string functions often (usually) result in poor query performance.  `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` *could* use indexes but frequently doesn't; `SUBSTRING()` can't.

Comment: I just want to make sure what you said is right. I tested LEFT and RIGHT, they are not using index. Any thought?

Comment: @FLICKER Yeah, that's why I said they _usually_ don't.  In fact they will typically get the same query plan as SUBSTRING does, so it's by and large a wash.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. obviously LEFT is tidier than SUBSTRING.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use replace in your join condition

```
on substring(tbl2.instancename, 1, CharIndex('\', tbl2.instancename) - 1) 
= tbl1.servername
```

Comment: Thanks FLICKER, i will try this...looks like this is what i needed.